# Extracting data from a column in a data frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I want to extract out the "A"(s) from this column. After doing that I want to be able to print the other data from other columns associated with "A" in the same row.
However, my code printed this instead:

```
outputs:
UniqueCarrier       NaN
CancellationCode    NaN
Name: CancellationCode, dtype: object
None
```

The column `CancellationCode` looks like this:

```
  CancellationCode:
        NaN
         A
        NaN
         B
        NaN
```

I want to get it to print in a data frame format with the filtered rows and columns.

Here is my code below:

```py
cancellation_reason = (flight_data_finalcopy["CancellationCode"] == "A")
cancellation_reasons_filtered = cancellation_reason[["UniqueCarrier", "AirlineID", "Origin"]]
print(display(cancellation_reasons_filtered))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
cancellation_reason=flight_data_finalcopy[flight_data_finalcopy["CancellationCode"] == "A"]
cancellation_reasons_filtered = cancellation_reason[["UniqueCarrier", "AirlineID", "Origin"]]
print(display(cancellation_reasons_filtered))
```

Comment: hey man thanks, I saw my mistake I needed another pair of square brackets and I was using parenthesis instead of the square brackets !